# override a method in order to add functions to it

Tags: flutter, dart

Let's say we have:

```
class Human{

    String name;

    Human(this.name);

    void printMyInfo(){
        print("My name is ${this.name}");
    }

}


class Bob extends Human{
    int age;

    Bob(this.name, this.age) : super(name);

}
```

Is there a way to add just the following line

```
print("My age is ${this.age}");
```

to printMyInfo() method inherited without rewrite the previous code?

My goal is to run obtain the following output:

```
My name is *;
My age is *;
```

By adding just the last print method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
class Bob extends Human{
    int age;
    Bob(this.name, this.age) : super(name);

    void printMyInfo(){
        super.printMyInfo();
        print("My age is $age");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply override your method. Add a call to super where you want to execute it.

```
@override
void printMyInfo(){
    super.printMyInfo();
    print("My age is ${this.age}");
}
```